# is antireligious a word?

Tags: questions

I think anti-religious should be a word because there is not really a word for against a certain religion what do you think? I have already tried other websites like google.

Comment: Anti-religious is a word.  Try looking in online dictionaries such as https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anti-religious, https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/antireligious, or https://www.dictionary.com/browse/antireligious

Answer (score 1):

**antireligious** or **anti-religious**

> opposing or hostile to religion or to the power and influence of organized religion

[From Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anti-religious)

In answer to your question, yes.